# Importing points from a DXF file into ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, dxf

I can import LineStrings, polygons, annotations from a DXF file into ArcMap (and arcpy) but I can't import Points from the same DXF file (neither with arcpy).

No error is reported, simply no features are loaded.

I am simply using the 'Add data' button in the GUI, then I select the layer in the DXF file. When I do it this way, I can 'Zoom to layer' to the correct extent of the layer, but nothing is displayed.

The DXF file version seems to be R12

And with arcpy:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(file + os.sep + "Point", self.temp_folder)
```

Everything works fine in QGIS 2.16.

Any idea how to make this possible?

Comment: What happens?  What is the process you follow to import the points?  Please [edit] your question to include as much information as possible about what you've tried.

Comment: You currently have an ArcPy tag.  If you are using ArcPy then please include a code snippet to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Have you tried CadToGeodatabase_conversion ?

Comment: Yes. Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong... Turns out that the layer I really wanted to load was the Annotation.

When loading the DXF file in QGIS, there is a choice of two layer: Point and linestring. In ArcMap there are: Point, Annotation, Linestring, Polygon. The points in QGIS is the layer I want. In ArcMap, the same layer is named Annotation and is displayed differently (annotations instead of points). Each annotation has a shape associated (point).

So I just had to change Point with Annotation in the python code:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(file + os.sep + "Point", self.temp_folder)
```

Should be:

```
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(file + os.sep + "Annotation", self.temp_folder)
```

Comment: I am having the same problem from CAD to GDB

Comment: Whats is os.sep?

Comment: 'os.sep' is the path separator depending on the OS. In Windows it is '\' and Linux is '/'. Very useful.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Since I just resolved it, maybe I can help.

Comment: You can read about Python's os module here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: I am going to write up a post later on and post a link here.